# Write Percentage values in Euro currency format using Kendo.culture

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am working to change number format of all numbers in my application using Kendo.culture as each numbers are in the grids.

Till now i have applied eg, kendo.culture('de-DE') for Euro so any number in the format like this 223.82 becomes this 222,82 .

But percentage values are also number, so the percentage value like this 99.99% do not becomes like this 99,99%. Is there any kendo's properties for percentage which i can refer to?

Comment: Is using `kendo` a requirement to achieve expected result?

Comment: Yes, The percentage values belong to the kendo grid, though kendo grid allows you to introduce custom function, i only need to use kendo.culture. I researched on it on kendo's official websites, but did not found any reference to kendo number format for percentage values